# error al mostrar titulo y descripcion de un evento cargando datos con eventSources

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

estoy usando la version de fullcalendar 3.4 y estoy cargando mis eventos con el método eventSources de la siguiente manera.

todo esto funciona perfecto,los eventos se cargan en el calendario sin problema, lo que pasa es que para yo poder ver el nombre que tiene cada evento en base de datos debo usar el metodo eventRender de la siguiente manera.

he probado identificando el elemento del DOM para la vista agendaWeek que segun su vista es .fc-widget-content y deberia verse el titulo y el nombre del evento como hace la vista listWeek y month, pero no lo hace.

info extra: he probado y se muestran los nombres de los eventos si cargo los eventos como un array.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

- una pregunta extra. Existe algun método de Fullcalendar que pueda usar para identificar que celda no tiene evento asociado? muchas gracias.

  ```
   `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // Rellenar calendario por defecto
              defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'listWeek,agendaWeek,agendaDay,month'
              },
              locale: 'es',
               eventSources: [
                  {
                  url: 'localhost/models/eventos.php',
                  },
                  {                        
                  url: 'http://localhost/models/eventos2.php',
                  //color: 'yellow',
                  //textColor: 'black'
                  color: '#4A2386',
                  borderColor: '#3547CB',
                  textColor: '#fff'

                  }
                  ],
           eventRender: function( event, element, view ) {
                if (view.name == "listWeek")
                {
                   element.find('.fc-list-item-title').html(event.titulo);
                }else if(view.name == 'month'){
                      element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + 
            event.nombre + "<br/>" + event.titulo);
                  }else if(view.name == 'agendaWeek'){
                      element.find('.fc-widget-content').append("<br/>" + 
              event.nombre + "<br/>" + event.titulo);
                  }
              }
    })
  ```

Comment: usando el metodo eventAfterRender 
`eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
                        if (view.name == "listWeek")
                          {
                             element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append(event.titulo);
                         }else{
                            element.append(event.titulo);
                        }
                    }
`
Me queda la duda de porque no se puede ver el titulo de un evento cargando los eventos en un json usando el método eventSources.Espero le pueda servir a otra persona.